# what is the best linq query for this

Tags: linq, collections

I have a collection of Calendar objects.  Calendar has a property **Id**.

```
IEnumerable<Calendar> CalendarsToView;
```

I have another collection of Event Objects.  Event objects have a property of **CalendarId**

```
IEnumerable<CalendarEvent> Events;
```

i want to filter the **Events** collection to only return events where the **calendarId** is in the CalendarsToView collection.

what is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do a join

```
var eventsIwant = from e in Events
                  from c in CalendarsToView
                  where c.calendarId =  e.CalendarId
                  select e
```

Answer (score 1):

This calls for an inner, equijoin:

```
var eventsInCalendar = from e in Events
                       join c in CalendarsToView on e.CalendarId equals c.Id
                       select e;

var distinctEventsInCalendar = eventsInCalendar.Distinct();
```

Here's another way of doing it with hash-sets:

```
var calendarIds = new HashSet<int>(CalendarsToView.Select(c => c.Id));
var distinctEventsInCalendar = Events.Where(e => calendarIds.Contains(e.CalendarId));
```